NtQueryInformation hanging
this doesn't work and iv been trying to figure out for about 30 minutes now and have no clue, anybodies help would be appreciated,
im trying to get chrome parameters for a project, this code is meant to read memory address and get the command line parameters using readprocessmemory and ntqueryinformationprocess
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <winternl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")

std::vector<DWORD> ChromePIDs;

int main() {
    // GETS ALL CHROME PIDS
    HANDLE CTH32 = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
    PROCESSENTRY32 ProcessEntry = { 0 };
    ProcessEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    if (CTH32 != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        while (Process32Next(CTH32, &ProcessEntry)) {
            if (std::wstring(ProcessEntry.szExeFile) == L"chrome.exe") {
                ChromePIDs.push_back(ProcessEntry.th32ProcessID);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "INVALID HANDLE VALUE\n";
    }

    // CHECKS EACH CHROME PROCESSES PARAMETERS
    PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION ProcessInfo;
    PULONG Length = nullptr;
    for (int x = 0; x < ChromePIDs.size(); x++) {
        HANDLE PHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, ChromePIDs[x]);
        if (PHandle == NULL) {
            std::cout << "Failed to open process ID: " << ChromePIDs[x] << "\n";
            continue; // Skip to the next PID
        }
        NTSTATUS status = NtQueryInformationProcess(PHandle, ProcessBasicInformation, &ProcessInfo, sizeof(ProcessInfo), Length);
        if (status != 0) {
            std::cout << "Failed to query information for process ID: " << ChromePIDs[x] << "\n";
            CloseHandle(PHandle);
            continue; // Skip to the next PID
        }
        PVOID BaseAddress = (void*)ProcessInfo.PebBaseAddress;
        PEB Peb;
        SIZE_T BytesRead = 0;
        if (ReadProcessMemory(PHandle, BaseAddress, &Peb, sizeof(Peb), &BytesRead)) {
            std::cout << "READ " << BytesRead << " BYTES FROM " << ChromePIDs[x] << "\n";
            RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS upp;
            if (ReadProcessMemory(PHandle, Peb.ProcessParameters, &upp, sizeof(upp), nullptr)) {
                std::cout << *upp.CommandLine.Buffer;
                wchar_t* CommandLineParemeters = new wchar_t[upp.CommandLine.Length / sizeof(wchar_t) + 1];
                if (ReadProcessMemory(PHandle, upp.CommandLine.Buffer, CommandLineParemeters, upp.CommandLine.Length, nullptr)) {
                    CommandLineParemeters[upp.CommandLine.Length / sizeof(wchar_t)] = L'\0'; // Null-terminate
                    std::wstring cmdLine(CommandLineParemeters);
                    std::wcout << CommandLineParemeters;
                }
                else {
                    std::cout << "FAILED AT 3";
                }
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "FAILED AT 2";
            }
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "FAILED AT 1";
        }
    }
}


Did you debug it line by line?

yes im almost certain it fails around " if (ReadProcessMemory(PHandle, Peb.ProcessParameters, &upp, sizeof(upp), nullptr)) {"

With a debugger you could remove that "almost[.]" Very handy tool, the debugger. It allows you to run a program at your speed and watch exactly what the program does as it does it. When you can see the program doing something unexpected, like store the wrong value or take the wrong branch, that's a bug spotted.

I was dereferencing a value that shouldn't have been dereferenced:
std::cout << *upp.CommandLine.Buffer;
//           ^ remove this *

